# Framerate dipping ~3 frames every ~1 second

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, frame

**Description of Problem:** Frame drops ~3FPS every second, happens in any game, and sort of noticeable on the Windows desktop also when shaking the mouse around really fast. Causes noticeable stuttering, almost like a "heartbeat" effect because it stutters one time per second.

**[Here's an example from DOOM Eternal's FPS counter](https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipPYsMS_KvB2lWWwmlZiXz7lg5wBJo_O-Vi8kSc0)**

---

**UserBenchmark:** https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/37531135

**DDU:** Tried it, no dice. Thought it would do the trick since I had an EVGA 1070 SC in here before. Although, it reverted to a low resolution, and the heartbeat effect seemed to have stopped.

**Computer Type:** Custom built

**GPU:** MSI Ventus 3x RTX 3080, running at 2x 1080p @ 60Hz (one is a 42" TV, one is a 22" monitor)

**CPU:** Ryzen 5800x

**Motherboard:** Aorus x570 Elite (F31Q Bios)

**RAM:** XMP on, G.Skill Trident Z Neo Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) PC4-28800 DDR4 3600MHz CL16-19-19-39 1.35V F4-3600C16D-16GTZNC

**PSU:** 850W Corsair RM850x

**Operating System & Version:** Windows 10 Pro v20H2

**GPU Drivers:** v460.89 (Released 12/15/2020, latest available). Tried rolling back to v460v.79 but the same issue occurs.

**Troubleshooting:** ‍♂️ - All of my stuff is up to date, not sure what to do. It's not a graphics setting problem, temperature problem, etc. & I've closed all background apps from the system tray to see if a rouge app was causing the issue. None of my stuff is overclocked. Issue persists on both monitors.

Some software that I run in the background (that I've closed to troubleshoot) includes:

- NZXT CAM
- GeForce Experience (Overlay off)
- Gigabyte app center
- RGB Fusion
- Steam
- Discord
- Windows defender

Answer (score 0):

Of all things - it was the HDMI cable going to my TV! For some reason my 3080 didn't like it, even though my 1070 had no problem with the same cables/displays. I swapped out my HDMI cable for a different one, and my frames at back at a consistent 60 FPS.